# Change JLists when JRadioButton is clicked

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception

In my GUI, I have 3 radio buttons that are part of the same ButtonGroup. I am trying to get it so that when any one button is clicked, a JList will appear. In my action listener, I have my JLists written but when I try to run it, I get a NullPointerException. I tried placing the JList outside of the action listener and it works, so I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my action listener. My buttons appear in the GUI as I want.

It is an inner class within the main GUI class:

```
    rbGenCancers = new JRadioButton("genCan");
    rbRelCancers = new JRadioButton("relCan");
    rbCancers = new JRadioButton("nonC");
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(rbGenCancers);
    bg.add(rbRelCancers);
    bg.add(rbCancers);

    JPanel rbButtons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(3, 2, 2));
    rbButtons.add(rbGenCancers);
    rbButtons.add(rbRelCancers);
    rbButtons.add(rbCancers);
    //added to the JFrame correctly through GridBagLayout and GridBagConstraints

 public class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch(e.getActionCommand()) {
            case "genCan":
                listModel = new DefaultListModel();
                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    cancerNames = _controller.selectGeneralCancer(i);
                    listModel.addElement(cancerNames);
                }
                cancerList = new JList(listModel);
                cancerList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                cancerList.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                cancerList.setVisibleRowCount(3);
                cancerListScroller = new JScrollPane(cancerList);
                break;
            case "relCan":
                listModel = new DefaultListModel();
                for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
                    split = _controller.readCancer(i);
                    cancerNames = split[0];
                    listModel.addElement(cancerNames);
                }
                cancerList = new JList(listModel);
                cancerList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                cancerList.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                cancerList.setVisibleRowCount(3);
                cancerListScroller = new JScrollPane(cancerList);
                break;
            case "nonC":
                listModel = new DefaultListModel();
                for(int i = 22; i < 36; i++) {
                    split = _controller.readCancer(i);
                    cancerNames = split[0];
                    listModel.addElement(cancerNames);
                }
                cancerList = new JList(listModel);
                cancerList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                cancerList.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                cancerList.setVisibleRowCount(3);
                cancerListScroller = new JScrollPane(cancerList);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the exception that is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1086)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:998)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:562)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
at Cancer.gui.CancerGUI.<init>(CancerGUI.java:306)
at Cancer.run.CancerApp.main(CancerApp.java:19)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Here is the class that executes all of the code. Line 19 in the printstack corresponds to CancerGUI _gui = new CancerGUI(); Line 306 in CancerGUI corresponds to where I add cancerListScroller to the JFrame through the GridBagConstraints.

```
public class CancerApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CancerGUI _gui = new CancerGUI();
    Disease _disease = new Disease();
    CancerController _controller = new CancerController(_disease, _gui);
    _gui.setController(_controller);

    CancerApp _app = new CancerApp();
    _app.run(_gui);
}

public void run(CancerGUI _gui) {
    _gui.setVisible(true);   
}
}
```

Comment: The error occurs in the `CancerGUI` constructor. Can you post that please.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thought.  The radio buttons work, but my action listener does not seem to set a new list with the setModel(listmodel).  I don't get an exception.  When I did get an exception, it was because of a type mismatch.  These can be infuriating.  I'm gonna double check to make sure the message is getting through, but it should.

```
    else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("chooseTitle"))
{
  jlst.setModel(lm);
}
```

Is it perhaps working ok, but I have to do something to make it display?